# Type: Error Message: Class 'CI_Controller' not found Filename: F:\wamp64\www\varient-v1.6.1\system\core\CodeIgniter.php Line Number: 369

Tags: codeigniter

Facing a strange error while using Codeigniter with wamp + php 7.1.16 + mysql 5.7.21 version

Type: Error

> Message: Class 'CI_Controller' not found
>
> Filename: F:\wamp64\www\varient-v1.6.1\system\core\CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 369

I already checked database.php and its credentials, it's all correct...

Please help...

Comment: Have you checked the spelling of your Controller Names? In CI the Controller File must be Start with Uppercase also the Controller Name.

Comment: in which file to check controller name....

Comment: Have you set CI error logging ?

Comment: try installing a fresh copy of codeigniter. `CI_Controller` comes with codeigniter, so unless you are using codeigniter in a really weird way, chances are it didn't copy over right.

Comment: I found the issue... It was that script should be pasted at root directory... not in any subdirectories..... I copied everything into root directory www. and it works...